# "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'"

Tags: python-2.7, split, attributeerror, nonetype

```
def get_par(filename_or_pard):

    # automatically search for the path

    Path = GetPathOsmosisPth()
    f = open(Path,'r')

    TheLines = f.readlines()
    Path = TheLines[0][0:-1] + '/osmosis/'
    f.close()

    # Get the name of the path to the data
    ThePath = locate_dir('GeneralParameters',Path)
    Thepdata = ThePath.split('GeneralParameters')[0]      #(line 216 - This line gives error) 

    # check if we do not have provided an external data path
    DataDir = CheckInputDataDirectory()
    #DataDir = 'Data_CS'
    if DataDir is None:
        pdata = Thepdata
    else:
        pdata = os.path.join(Path,DataDir)

    # search for the file

    if isstring(filename_or_pard):
        # myprintv("isstring: ", filename_or_pard)
        # creating the dictionary
        ThePath = locate(filename_or_pard,pdata)
        f = ThePath + os.path.sep + filename_or_pard
        pard = create_par_structure(f)

        # creating the class par_struct
        par = par_struct(pard)

        # store the filename with the parameters in the par structure

        par.TheFilename = filename_or_pard
    else:
        # myprint2v("not isstring: ", filename_or_pard, type(filename_or_pard))
        # the dictionary is provided as input
        pard = filename_or_pard

        # creating the class par_struct
        if isdict(pard):
            par = par_struct(pard)
            par._FromStringToTrueType()
        else:
            par = pard

    # if parameters.txt, set the path_data

    if hasattr(par,'path_data'):
        par.path_data = pdata
        par.root_path = Path
        # myprintv("pdata: ", par.path_data)

    if hasattr(par,'path_packages'):
        par.path_packages = os.path.join(Path,par.path_packages)

    # returning the result
    return par
```

When i run my program i get an error with both split methods used above. The error displayed is

line 216, in get_par
    Thepdata = ThePath.split('GeneralParameters', Path)[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

I believe i am making a small error but i dont know, just starting programing.

Thanking you in advance

Comment: Where is `locate_dir` defined?

Comment: `locate_dir()` returned `None`. Add that function to your question.

Comment: Please add the code to your question and format it properly! Do you by chance happen to get the message "Warning in locate: No directory found!"? Note that you should raise an error if you do not wish to return anything, but calling code expects something.

Comment: The Locate_dir() returns path

Answer (score 0):

Your function `locate_dir` returns `None`. This happens if `pattern` never matches a path. Since you use your own print function `myprinte`, you are probably suppressing your error message.

This is assuming your `locate_dir` is currently formatted as below.
Formatted based on your comment:

```
def locate_dir(pattern, r=os.curdir):
  ok = 0
  for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(r)):
    if pattern in path:
      ok = 1
      return path
  if ok == 0:  # ok will always be 0 here, you would have left the loop otherwise
    myprinte("Warning in locate: No directory found!")
  # end of function *implicitly* returns None (i.e. returns "Nothing")
```

Note that you should raise an Exception if your code fails to produce a result that other code requires.

```
def locate_dir(pattern, r=os.curdir):
  for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(r)):
    if pattern in path:
      return path
  raise FileNotFoundError("No file found for pattern %s" % pattern)
```

This way, you do not accidentally suppress errors.

Comment: I want to add that when i run the same code on window machine it runs properly, but when I run it on Ubuntu it gives me Attribute error.

I found myself unable to correct it. If you can it for me I shall send you the code through email if you find some time for me.

Thanking you in advance

Comment: @FazalHaq The problem as a whole is in your environment. Namely, there is no path matching your desired pattern. No amount of fixing code will make that pattern appear. Only you can know what environment you are working on and how to fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply and time spared for me. I shall check the problem in depth. May be someday I'll come to some fruitful results. 

Thank you everybody for such a nice cooperation.